# can I run elementary os on Vaio Z1?

Tags: system-installation

can I run elementary os on Vaio Z1?
Intel Pentium 1.7GHz
14.1 SXGA TFT display (1400 x 1050)
512MB DDR SDRAM
60GB Hard Drive

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to eOS!

Unfortunately, your notebook does not meet the minimum RAM requirements for Elementary OS, not to mention some of the other hardware. Based on [the installation page](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation), you will need at least the following:

- Recent Intel i3 or comparable dual-core 64-bit processor
- 4 GB of system memory (RAM)
- Solid state drive (SSD) with 15 GB of free space
- Internet access
- Built-in or wired mouse/touchpad and keyboard
- 1024×768 minimum resolution display

Using the specs you've outlined, Google tells me that you are *probably* using a VAIO Z1WA from Mid-2004, which comes with the following specifications:

| Category | Specification | Yay or Nay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **CPU:** | Intel Pentium 1.7GHz processor | Insufficient |
| **RAM:** | 512MB DDR SDRAM | Insufficient |
| **Storage:** | 60GB Hard Drive (4200rpm) | You will find this too slow |
| **Display:** | 14.1 SXGA TFT display (1400 x 1050) | Meets Requirements |
| **Optical:** | Integrated CD-RW/DVD-ROM | Likely Compatible |
| **Network:** | Integrated 802.11 b/g Wireless | Likely Compatible |

While I am a strong proponent of using computer hardware for as long as possible (my main machine is from 2013 and my phone is from 2014!), this particular computer will not be able to run most of the modern Linux distributions. Aside from the lack of RAM, the processor is [a 32-bit single-core CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/27578/intel-pentium-m-processor-1-70-ghz-1m-cache-400-mhz-fsb.html).

That said, all is not lost. Your computer *may* have enough power to run [Zorin OS Lite](https://zorin.com/os/download/15/lite/) or [Bodhi Linux](https://www.bodhilinux.com/download/), which are two actively maintained Linux distributions.

Comment: yes, I thought so. Thanks sir.